# Translate "min-content" to pixels

Tags: css, reactjs

I use MaterialUI for React and on their AppBar component there is this piece of code:

```
 [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: `100px`,
      "&:focus": {
        width: `150px`,
      },
```

Which means that when you click on the AppBar, it grows from 100px to 150px in a nice effect.
I wanted to change 100px to `min-content` because the placeholder text is longer than 100px.
I tried something like this:

```
 [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: `calc(min-content + 10px)`,
      "&:focus": {
        width: `calc(min-content + 60px)`,
      },
```

But it didn't work.
What's the right way keep it responsive with `min-content` and still be recognized as a number?

Comment: `min-content` **isn't** a number so you would have to get the computed width and then add your 60px etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know that's what I tried to do with calc() as shown in the example above.